# How to put "format" button on the Toolbar In NetBeans IDE

Tags: format, netbeans, toolbar

How to put "format" button on the Toolbar In NetBeans IDE?

I cannot event find this item in the menu, it is only in right click menu, when you select some text.

I use Netbeans IDE 8.2 for Mac.

Comment: It doesn't look like "format" is available, do you know there's a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: No, what is a shortcut?

Comment: A keyboard shortcut is pressing one or more buttons that executes a command. For example to "Format" a code selection you can press: Alt-Shift-F